# Why does doublespacing using setspace have errors when used in a minimal documentclass?

Tags: errors, setspace

Just curious why `\doublespacing` seems broken in a minimal document.  It works ok when the documentclass is set to article.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}

doublespace

these

lines

\end{document}
```

First error is

```
! Undefined control sequence.

\setstretch ...ef \baselinestretch {#1}\@currsize
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`setspace` depends on `\@currsize` being set by the documentclass to set the current font size. The `minimal` document class is very minimal and doesn't contain this macro. It doesn't even have things like `\large`.

Comment: Indeed, the `minimal` class is unfortunately pretty bad at supporting a lot of standard stuff, hence the recommendation that minimal examples should not use it!

Answer (score 11):

The UC Berkeley thesis class (and apparently others) have this problem as well.  A  [workaround](http://kevin.saff.net/2007/07/26/bug-in-thesis-classfile-for-latex-regarding-currsize-and-the-setspace-package-undefined-control-sequence/) is to include the following code before using the spacing commands from setspace:

```
\makeatletter
\let\@currsize\normalsize
\makeatother
```