# Double spaced document with exceptions

Tags: spacing

I have to set the line space among my thesis double. So I use the following commands at preamble

```
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.8}
```

However, the line space at the following items should be untouched and regular:

- Captions
- Footnotes
- Bibliography entries of more than one line

What commands should I add?

Comment: `\usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing`.

Comment: @cfr - Depending on the main document font size, `\doublespacing` is equivalent to `\setstretch` with a factor somewhere between 1.618 and 1.667. Since the OP appears to be interested in a factor of 1.8, I'd use `\setstretch{1.8}`.

Comment: @Mico Maybe. But then that's more than double-spaced. So it depends if it is double-spacing or something else that's wanted. @ OP You can use `\begin{singlespace}... \end{singlespace}` or you can say `\singlespacing` to switch indefinitely, although the `\...ing` versions are intended primarily for preamble use.

Comment: @cfr - Unfortunately, the term "double-spacing" isn't defined uniformly and consistently. E.g., whereas `setspace` uses a stretch factor somewhere between 1.618 and 1.667, MS Word, I believe, uses a stretch factor of 2.0 (yikes!).

Comment: @Mico Yes, but MS Word uses less line spacing by default, doesn't it? So when people mean Word-double-spacing, the LaTeX equivalent is not straightfoward to compute. (Generally if people ask for this, they mean Word and they seem to find `setspace`'s double-spacing acceptable. Same for one-half-spacing. Even my thesis office accepted this - and they got out a ruler to inspect my draft submission, complaining the title was 2mm too high!)

Comment: @cfr - So, your argument is really with the OP's use of the factor 1.8 to achieve double-spacing, isn't it?

Comment: @Mico `argument` is probably too strong. If the OP is sure this is what they need, this is what they need. But `setspace`'s defaults are based on the fact that the base line spacing exceeds `1`. So to get `2`, you don't need a factor of `2`.... At least, so I understand it.

Comment: @cfr  What you suggested resolved the issue. I  enclose the text of my document within  `\begin{doublespacing}  \end{doublespacing}`  and the `printbibliography` within `\begin{singlespacing}`  `\end{singlespacing}` and now text of document is doubled line spaced while the references are single  line spaced.

Comment: @cfr   While your approach works very well in applying different line space to text and reference section of my document, I still dont have control over the exact line space. Is there any way we combine `\begin{doublespacing}\end{doublespacing} ` and `\setstretch{1.8}`?

Comment: @Mahdi `\begin{doublespace}` or `\doublespacing`, it should be really. (Although you can use commands as environments, I think. (I always confuse myself about this so try not to do it at all.) But, yes. You can combine `\setstretch` with `\begin{doublespace}` or `\begin{singlespace}` or you can say `\begin{spacing}{1.8}...\end{spacing}`. Any combination is possible. The exception is that you can't use the `onehalfspace` environment within a `doublespace` environment or within the scope of `\doublespacing`. But you don't want one-half-spacing at all, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Why don't you say `\setstretch{1.8}` in the preamble and then put `\begin{singlespace}... \end{singlespace}` around the bibliography? Will that work?

Comment: @cfr yes. this works very well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[setspace](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/setspace) provides 4 commands intended for use in the preamble:

- `\singlespacing`
- `\doublespacing`
- `\onehalfspacing`
- `\setstretch{<factor>}`

Alternatively, the package options `singlespacing`, `onehalfspacing` or `doublespacing` may be used in place of the first three. `singlespacing` is default.

In addition, a further option `nodisplayskipstretch` may be set to prevent extra spacing around display environments. Alternatively, this spacing may be manually adjusted with `\setdisplayskipstretch{<factor>}`.

For use in the body of the document, the package provides 4 environments:

- `\begin{singlespace}...\end{singlespace}`
- `\begin{singlespace*}...\end{singlespace*}`
- `\begin{onehalfspace}...\end{onehalfspace}`
- `\begin{doublespace}...\end{doublespace}`
- `\begin{spacing}{<factor>}...\end{spacing}`

Although the preamble commands will work in the document body, they are not designed for use there and will result in sub-optimal spacing in many cases. This is because the environments do more than simply switch the stretch using the `\...ing` commands.

For example, here's the definition of `singlespace`:

```
\newenvironment{singlespace}{% from setspace.sty
  \vskip \baselineskip
  \setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}%
  \vskip -\baselineskip
}{%
  \par
}
```

In contrast, here's the definition of `\singlespacing`:

```
\newcommand{\singlespacing}{% from setspace.sty
  \setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}%  normally 1
  \vskip \baselineskip  % Correction for coming into singlespace
}
```

While `\setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}` is the same in both definitions, the adjustments differ in other ways because the environment makes adjustments specifically required in the case of line spacing *changes* within a document.

The difference between `singlespace` and `singlespace*` is in the specific adjustments made. Here's `singlespace*`:

```
\newenvironment{singlespace*}{% from setspace.sty
  \setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}%
  \vskip -\baselineskip
}{%
  \vskip -0.5\baselineskip
}
```

As can be seen, the vertical spacing changes differ between the two environments and between both environments and `\singlespacing`.

Similar differences exist for the other preamble command/corresponding environment pairs.

In general, therefore, it is best to use the environments intended for use within the body within the body. In some cases, the differences will not change the output because, for example, there's a page break at the start and end of the changed line-spacing anyway. But the differences will matter in other cases so it is best to use the environments as a routine within the document body unless there is some special reason to do otherwise.

```
\documentclass...
...
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.8}
...
\begin{document}
...
\begin{singlespace}
<bibliography commands go here>
\end{singlespace}
...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't modify the low-level parameter `\baselinestretch` directly. Instead, insert the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.8}
```

Or, use a `spacing` environment with an argument of 1.8, in the body of the document:

```
\begin{spacing}{1.8}
 ...
\end{spacing}
```

Just let the `spacing` environment end before the start of the bibliography.

An MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{1.8}
\lipsum*[1]\footnote{\lipsum*[2]}  % automatic single-spacing in footnotes

\end{spacing}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{z} xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx 

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I add the command `\setstrech{1.8}` I get the error  `\setstretch ...ef \baselinestretch {#1}\@currsize`.  I resolve this issue by adding the few commands  `\makeatletter
\let\@currsize\normalsize
\makeatother`  and then add `\setstrech{1.8}`.   However, the space line in references is larger than regular.

Comment: @Mahdi - Do issue the instruction `\setstretch{1.0}` -- or, equivalently, `\singlespacing` -- *before* the start of the bibliography.

Comment: To see why I modify `@currsize`, please see the following link  `http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15442/why-does-doublespacing-using-setspace-have-errors-when-used-in-a-minimal-documen`. Yes I removed  `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.8}`.  We cannot add the command `\singlespacing` before the start of bibliography, because `\singlespacing` can be added to preamble only.  Instead I used `\begin{singlespace}  \printbibliography \end{singlespace}` and this later command resolved the issue.

Comment: @Mico `\baselinestretch` isn't low-level TeX parameter because I don't know it.

Comment: @wipet - You're absolutely right! :-) I must have been thinking of `\baselineskip`... Indeed, `\baselinespread` is defined in `latex.ltx`, the LaTeX "kernel". I will edit my answer to remove the word "TeX".

Comment: @Mahdi - Are you really using the `minimal` document class? You should have mentioned this rather important fact up-front. About the macro `\singlespacing`: Why do you believe that it can only be used in the preamble?

Comment: @mico  I am sorry for not mentioning my document class, as I am  a beginner latex user. I am using our university template  `\documentclass[oneside,final, letterpaper, 12 pt]{University_Template}`  so I don't know if I am using `minimal` or not.  Since @cfr  comments that `\singlespacing` are intended to be used in preamble, I thought we cannot use it within  `\begin{document}\end{document}`. But I now see  that `\singlespacing` can be used  both inside and outside of preamble.

Comment: @Mico `setspace` says it is intended for use in the preamble and the `singlespace` environment for use in the body. The environment does more than just `\singlespacing`. Although it doesn't matter here, it would in other cases.

Comment: @Mahdi It works in the body, too, but it isn't intended for use there. In your case, I don't think it will make any difference because you have a new page, probably, at the start and end of the stretch of single-spaced references. But in other cases, you will lose the spacing adjustments the package makes when using `singlespace` but not when saying `\singlespacing`. So it is better to use `singlespace` within the body as routine.

Comment: @Mahdi - I don't have access to a copy of the `University_Template.cls` file, but I'd say that it's exceedingly unlikely that the class file is based on the `minimal` class. Thus, I wouldn't worry about a discussion that's applicable to users of the `minimal` document class only.