# Could you please help me figure out what's the problem with this code?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[12pt]{ucalgthes1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=1in, bottom= 1in, left= 1in, right= 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[braket]{qcircuit}

%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\fancyhead{}
%\fancyfoot{}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
%Define other usepackages here
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{steps}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[steps, 1]{label = Step \arabic*:}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\usepackage[braket]{qcircuit}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}






\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (1.8,4.8) {n};
    \draw (1.8,2) circle (2.5cm) ;
    \draw (2.6,1.1) circle (1cm) node {$k$};
    \draw (1,2.9) circle (1cm) node {$k$};
    \draw [draw=blue,line width=3mm ,->,>=stealth] (2.1,2.9) -- (6,2.9);
    \draw [draw=blue,line width=3mm ,->,>=stealth] (3.7,1) -- (6,1);
    \node at (6.5,1) {$\ket{s}$};
    \node at (6.5,2.9) {$\ket{s}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{fig:label}
\caption{Blah blah blah text.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I don't use the figure command the code works well, but I need to use figure as I want to write a caption and also refer to the picture

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: You should make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) by removing all unused packages and use a standard class like `article` instead of `ucalgthes1`, because nobody can test it with that.

Comment: It works here if you insert `\begin{document}` and replace the class `ucalgthes1` by `report` one.  Also, maybe you wish `$n$` in the 1st node.

Comment: I have to use ucalgthes1 as it's the only class which is approved by university.

Comment: your preamble need to be clean. remove all double loaded  packages, see if your mwe works of you temporally remove `\usepackage[braket]{qcircuit}`. `hyperref` with rare exception had to be last in the preamble. also `\label {...}` had to be after `\caption{...}` ...

Comment: Is that a `tikzpicture` containing nothing but another `tikzpicture`? o( o_o )o Maybe removing the outer `\begin` and `\end` might do some good.

Comment: Off-topic for the present query, but relevant nevertheless: `\caption` instructions must come before, not after, the associated `\label` instructions.

Comment: `tikzpicture` environments ought never to be nested anyway.

Comment: Now it is worse: you have a `\begin` with no `\end` as you've only de-duplicated the head - not the tail.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

This is a minimal soulution to your problem. If can add your code, to maybe reproduce your error.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{braket}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (1.8,4.8) {n};
    \draw (1.8,2) circle (2.5cm) ;
    \draw (2.6,1.1) circle (1cm) node {$k$};
    \draw (1,2.9) circle (1cm) node {$k$};
    \draw [draw=blue,line width=3mm ,->,>=stealth] (2.1,2.9) -- (6,2.9);
    \draw [draw=blue,line width=3mm ,->,>=stealth] (3.7,1) -- (6,1);
    \node at (6.5,1) {$\ket{s}$}; 
    \node at (6.5,2.9) {$\ket{s}$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Blah blah blah text.}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

### EDIT

Here is your code working with everything (except that no packages are loaded twice). It's better to have it fix because you are make more mistakes while fixing your code. Work with an MWE next time. You'll help yourself.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[braket]{qcircuit}

%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\fancyhead{}
%\fancyfoot{}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}

%% Load other packages here

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{steps}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[steps, 1]{label = Step \arabic*:}

\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}   % is this really needed??

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{amsmath} % is loaded automatically by 'mathtools' package
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{hyperref} % don't load this package twice!
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]

%\usepackage[braket]{qcircuit} % has already been loaded 
\usepackage{psfrag}
% \usepackage{amsmath}  % has already been loaded 
% \usepackage{amssymb}  % has already been loaded 
\usepackage{dsfont}

\usepackage{hyperref} % load this package *last*

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \node at (1.8,4.8) {n};
    \draw (1.8,2) circle (2.5cm) ;
    \draw (2.6,1.1) circle (1cm) node {$k$};
    \draw (1,2.9) circle (1cm) node {$k$};
    \draw [draw=blue,line width=3mm ,->,>=stealth] (2.1,2.9) -- (6,2.9);
    \draw [draw=blue,line width=3mm ,->,>=stealth] (3.7,1) -- (6,1);
    \node at (6.5,1) {$\ket{s}$};
    \node at (6.5,2.9) {$\ket{s}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Blah blah blah text.}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The nested `tikzpicture` environments add space or something, but that's a really strange way to do this… I would definitely remove the first `\begin{tikzpicture}` end the corresponding `\end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: @alice Yes, you're right. I didn't see it while copying the code from the questing.

Comment: The `\ket` macro is defined in the `braket` package that's loaded in the OP's preamble.

Comment: Does this still show the problem? If not, it is not an MWE.

Comment: it has to be \ket{s}

Comment: @Mico I've updated it .

Comment: @Masoud I've edited your last edit. It's working now. But please help yourself and break down your problems to MWE.

Comment: @cfr I think it is a MWE because the example in the question is not working. And if Masoud would break down his problem, he would find a MWE on his own. The question would never been asked. But I've changed it to 'solution'.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your code to eliminate double-loading of packages. Feel free to revert if you disagree. :-)

Comment: @Mico Thanks. I just copied the code from the question. Because I thought it is not worth to check for all the mistakes because of my first example.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean [this class template](http://grad.ucalgary.ca/current/thesis/latex-template). It uses the [`doublespace`](https://ctan.org/pkg/doublespace) package which is obsolete. Using [`setspace`](https://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) instead seems to fix the error you were probably getting (`! Too many }'s. \color@endbox ->\color@endgroup \egroup`).

Changes I made to the `ucalgthes1.cls` file to get it work:

- Replaced `\input doublespace.sty %(nm 2007 re-instated)` with `\RequirePackage{setspace}`.
- Added `\let\@currsize\normalsize` before the last line (`\setstretch{1.7}`) - see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15442/) for an explanation.

Now the following MWE should work (a cleaned up version of the answer of *goofyno*):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{ucalgthes1}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (1.8,4.8) {$n$};
    \draw (1.8,2) circle (2.5cm) ;
    \draw (2.6,1.1) circle (1cm) node {$k$};
    \draw (1,2.9) circle (1cm) node {$k$};
    \draw [draw=blue,line width=3mm ,->,>=stealth] (2.1,2.9) -- (6,2.9);
    \draw [draw=blue,line width=3mm ,->,>=stealth] (3.7,1) -- (6,1);
    \node at (6.5,1) {$\ket{s}$};
    \node at (6.5,2.9) {$\ket{s}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Blah blah blah text.}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note: Seems like there had been a change to the template in 2005 to use `setspace` which has been reverted in 2007: `%\RequirePackage{setspace}[200/12/01] %(NM2005) replacing old doublespace.sty %singlespace,onehalfspace and doublespacing options. (nm2007 commented out)%`